# Project Euler 4 - Won't print result

Tags: java

Here's the question

> "A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99. 
> Find
>   the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers."

I'm not sure why my code doesn't work. I reasoned that if i start with the largest number and decrease X each time, then the first palindrome number that I find is it. But for some reason it's not printing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Euler4 {

  public static void main(String[] args){ 
    for (int x=999*999; x>=100*100; x--){
      String num=Integer.toString(x);
      StringBuilder num1 = new StringBuilder(num);
      String num2 = num1.toString();
      if (num2.equals(num1.reverse())==true)
      System.out.println(num);
      break;
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beside moving the break into the if block, keep in mind that you need the largest number that is a product of 2 three digits number (you are currently just finding the largest number less than 999*999)

Answer (score 4):

Your loop loops only one time, since you have `break;`. Add braces to prevent such a things in the future:

```
if (num2.equals(num1.reverse().toString())) {
      System.out.println(num);
      break;
}
```

Also note that it's redundant to write `if(someBoolean == true)`, just write `if(someBoolean)` to prevent assignment by mistake (`=` instead of `==`). And please.. Indent your code!

To be honest with you, I didn't notice that when I looked at your code, but I used a debugger and found the problem in less than 5 seconds. There is a debugger.. Use it!

Comment: In addition the comparison is between `String` and `StringBuilder` which will always give `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is indented poorly, which is why you haven't found the error. You break after every iteration.

```
if (num2.equals(num1.reverse())==true) {
    System.out.println(num);
    break;
}
```

Not using braces around if statements is okay, but I suggest that while learning you try to put them around everything.

Answer (score 0):

Put braces around your `if` statement:

```
if (num2.equals(num1.reverse())==true) {
  System.out.println(num);
  break;
}
```

Not using braces will only execute the first statement after the condition as part of the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of `StringBuilder` and `num2` and check ik like so:

```
if (num.equals(num.reverse())) {
    //...
}
```

This way you can find a palindrome, but there's no confidence that it'll be made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. It can be a product of two prime numbers, one 2-digit and the second 4-digit. You have to check the product of all 3-digit numbers and see if it makes a palindrome.